# R: How to run calculation on a part of the df without previous subsetting?

Tags: r, subset

I want to apply a percentage calculation on certain rows (according to column criteria) of my data set. Normally I would do a (1) subset for this, (2) calculate the percentage, (3) delete the old (or previously subsetted rows) in my original data and (4) finally stack them together via rbind().

My question is there a better/faster/shorter way to do this calculation? Here some example data:

```
df <- data.frame(object = c("apples","tomatoes", "apples","pears" ),
                 Value = c(50,10,30,40))
```

The percentage calculation (50%) I would like to use for the subset on e.g. apples:

```
sub[,2] <- sub$Value * 50 /100
```

And the result should look like this:

```
    object Value
1   apples    25
2 tomatoes    10
3   apples    15
4    pears    40
```

Thank you. Probably there is an easy way, but I didn't find online a solution so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a logical index for 'object' that are `apples' and do the calculation only the subset of 'Value' based on the 'index'.

```
 i1 <- df$object=='apples'
 df$Value[i1] <- df$Value[i1]*50/100
```

Or you can use `ifelse`

```
 df$Value <- with(df, ifelse(object=='apples', Value*50/100, Value))
```

Or a more faster approach would be `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[object=='apples', Value := Value*0.5]
```

Comment: or more functional programming oriented, `transform(df, new=replace(Value, object=='apples', Value[object=='apples']*0.5))`

Comment: thank you very much, I didn't understand this before:)